# Place shortcode in php template file

Tags: php, wordpress, function, shortcode, codex

this has been discussed before however it's not working for me. As the shortcode seems to be a mix of regular and open-close shortcode. Or a combination of nested shortcodes.

```
// Use shortcode in a PHP file (outside the post editor).
echo do_shortcode( '' );

// In case there is opening and closing shortcode.
echo do_shortcode( '[iscorrect]' . $text_to_be_wrapped_in_shortcode . '[/iscorrect]' );
```

This is the shortcode I would like to display in my php template

```
[mk_page_section bg_stretch="true" full_width="true" padding_top="0" padding_bottom="0" sidebar="sidebar-1"][vc_column][mk_header hover_styles="5" logo="false"][/vc_column][/mk_page_section]
```

What I am trying to achieve is display my main navigation on a webinar page that doesn't use my themes header or footer.

Is mit possible to use it like this?

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[mk_page_section bg_stretch="true" full_width="true" padding_top="0" padding_bottom="0" sidebar="sidebar-1"][vc_column][mk_header hover_styles="5" logo="false"][/vc_column][/mk_page_section]'); ?>
```

Or must it be a combination? totally lost here...

Why is the do_shortcode not working?

Comment: What is actually happening when you try that? It looks reasonable to my rusty eyes.

Comment: In case of nested shortcodes, you need to manually execute each of them since Wordpress doesn't recognise the shortcodes inside. Check this link for more information https://www.sitepoint.com/wordpress-nested-shortcodes/

Comment: All it does is display the shortcode as text on my page. If the shortcode is pasted in visual composer it shows my main navigation menu just as it should.